# Attempting to show array element of react select in list item

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, react-select

I am using react-select to store multiple elements and am using the map function to display elements which is working fine. But when I am using the same element in another class to display in a list element it shows a blank.

Here is the code where I am displaying the multiple options.

```
const Departments = [
  { label: "OneIT", value: "OneIT" },
  { label: "HR", value: "HR" },
  { label: "Vigilance", value: "Vigilance" },
  { label: "Ethics", value: "Ethics" },
  { label: "Corporate Services", value: "Corporate Services" },
  { label: "Legal", value: "Legal" },
  { label: "Sports", value: "Sports" },
  { label: "TQM", value: "TQM" },
  { label: "Iron Making", value: "Iron Making" },
  { label: "TMH", value: "TMH" }
];

class MultiSelect2 extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOptions: []
  };
  handleChangeField = selectedOptions => {
    this.setState({ selectedOptions });
  };
  render() {
    const { selectedOption } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col-md-2"></div>
          <div className="col-md-8">
            <span>Select Department</span>
            <Select
              value={selectedOption}
              options={Departments}
              onChange={this.handleChangeField}
              isMulti
            />
            {this.state.selectedOptions.map(o => (
              <p>{o.value}</p>
            ))}
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-4"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I am trying to display this in another class in the list item but it is not showing.

```
export class Confirm extends Component {
  state = {
    selectedOptions: []
  };

 render() {
    const {
      values: {selectedOptions
      }
    } = this.props;
return (
<List>
            <ListItemText primary="Departments" secondary={selectedOptions} />
</List>
```

Comment: Your Confirm component is anywhere in the MultiSelect2 components, so you are not rendering it and not passing it the prop values with selectedOptions

Comment: Did not under stand what do you mean by is anywhere in the  component